# C++: Windows Bash console sometime displays Spanish characters as blocks

Tags: c++, bash, encoding

I am making a program that reads a `.txt` file and generates text based on the probabilities of the words in the file.

For texts with more than 10000 different words, I only use the 10000 words with more occurrences. I am pasting the fragment of the code that I think is relevant:

```
vector<pair<int,string>> sorted_words; //Vector with all the words from the .txt associated with the number of occurrences in the .txt, sorted by occurrences (value)
map<string,float> used_words; //map with the words associated with their percentage
int total_count=0; //total words in the .txt
int partial_count=0;  //number of occurrences of the words that are going to be taken into account

/* Code where I calculate total_words and fill and sort sorted_words */

//dumping the 10000 pairs with more occurrences in a map, replacing the number of occurrences with the probabilities
if(sorted_words.size()>=10000){
    vector<pair<int,string>>::iterator it = sorted_words.begin();
    for(int used_count=0; used_count<10000; used_count++) {
        partial_count+=it->first;
        it++;
    }
    it = sorted_words.begin();
    for(int used_count=0; used_count<10000; used_count++) {
        used_words.insert(make_pair(it->second,(float)it->first/partial_count));
        it++;
    }
}
else{
    partial_count = total_count;
    for(auto i: sorted_words) {
        used_words.insert(make_pair(i.second,(float)i.first/total_count));
    }
}
```

And my console prints out correctly the Spanish characters when the `.txt` file has less than 10000 different words but squared blocks when more. I guess it has something to do with how the `iterator` takes the `string`. Why does this happen?

EDIT:
Screenshot of the problem:

[.txt with more than 10000 different words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiISs.png)

[.txt with less than 10000 different words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JeV2.png)

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to check why it doesn't work, i don't know where `partial_count` or `total_count`  come from

Comment: @alseether Thank you, I have added context to my previous code and provided screenshots of the execution.

Comment: @Wrfyng It doesn't seem to be a programming issue. Can may be the encoding of your files? Are you opening them in distinct ways? Could you share the code with the file writing?

Comment: @alseether I am opening them the same way: `ifstream file; file.open(argv[1]); if (!file.is_open()) return 0;`

Comment: **"I am pasting the fragment of the code that I think is relevant"** don't do that, give us enough to **reproduce** the problem.